# Android: ListView CursorAdapter Crash On Database Change?

Tags: android, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have a listview backed by a cursor adapter. 
However, when I go to make a change in the database on a background sync, the app crashes with the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 0
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:248)
        at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:232)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2842)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1884)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1364)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1671)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2632)
```

Furthermore, the data I am adding clears the database and inserts no data at all. I am confused as I thought the cursor was asynchronous to the database.

The crash occurs between the end of the sync and when I send a broadcast to notify the activity that the sync is finished. The broadcast receiver does not even receive the broadcast.

My question is how can I multithread this? That is, how can I clear and change the database, then update the cursor afterwards on activity after the sync is finished?

Comment: use notifydatasetchanged() method after the modification of data instead doing it manually

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by 'I though the cursor was asynchronous to the database', if you want to update the table in one thread while continuing to display a listview it's always safer to use ContentProviders and Loaders.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the getLoaderManager().initLoader() because that was automatically managing my cursor.